# NodeJS seems to execute 2 calls to the same function in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, axios, interceptor

I have an axios interceptor

```
let authTokenRequest = null

axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, err => {
  const error = err.response
  if (error.status === 401 && error.config && !error.config.__isRetryRequest) {
    return getAuthToken()
      .then(response => {
        saveTokens(response.data)
        error.config.__isRetryRequest = true
        return axios(error.config)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        throw e 
      })
      .finally(() => {
        authTokenRequest = null
      })
  }
})
```

This calls the following function

```
function getAuthToken() {
  if (!authTokenRequest) {
    authTokenRequest = RefreshToken();
  }
  return authTokenRequest;
}
```

So I'd expect the RefreshToken function to only be called once.

But it's called twice in quick succession, even tho authTokenRequest is quickly assigned the promise inside the if statement making it truthy - so a second call should not be possible?

This behaves correctly in the browser but not in NodeJS, any reason why?

Comment: Probably not part of your problem, but the `resolve(e)` does not seem to belong here at all.  There is no `resolve()` function in this code.

Comment: You're right, I pasted old code where I had it nested inside a new Promise.

Even with the throw, the problem is still there :(

Comment: What is the scope of `authTokenRequest`?  Where is it defined?  And, can you show the calling code that triggers all this?

Comment: @jfriend00 I just edited it, `authTokenRequest` is declared outside `getAuthToken` at the top of the file.

It's triggered when an axios response comes back as failed - the axios response interceptor triggers it.